# I cannot open my ssis package after i renamed it

Tags: ssis

I have created a ssis package and renamed it. Worked on it and made some changes.  I closed my project. When i was trying to open the same package on monday morning i was getting the error below.

The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved.

Some one please help me with this.

Comment: I think you would have changed the ssis package. but, not saved the ssis project.So, the project is not able to find the file.

Comment: I renamed the file before creating data flows and i saved straight away after that.

Comment: I think you have saved the file. but, not saved the project. I would suggest you to add package to existing project again and save the project.

Comment: to add to @VenkataramanR. Move the package outside the bin so when you reattach you don't get the (1) added to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new Solution then add your `package.dtsx` to the new solution.